# limit Apache HTTPD to one client IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, httpd.conf

When an Apache HTTPD is used as a load balancer, is it possible to configure it on a way that all the requests are rejected except those coming from a specific host?
What directive should be used?

Answer (score 2):

For **Apache 2.2** you should use:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from x.x.x.x
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /  http://yoursite.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://yoursite.com/
```

For **Apache 2.4** you should use:

```
<Proxy *>
    Require ip x.x.x.x
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /  http://yoursite.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://yoursite.com/
```